# Get all Items attached to sellerId - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

When execute my query i just get 1 item back that i attached to the sellerId instead of 2. Does anyone know how i can say?

select the name of item and re seller for each item that belongs to the re seller. With a rating higher than 4?

Current Query:

```
SELECT items.name, sellers.name
FROM items
inner JOIN sellers
on items.id=sellers.id
WHERE rating > 4
ORDER BY sellerId
```

The query for tables inc. data:

```
CREATE TABLE sellers (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  rating INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE items (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  sellerId INTEGER REFERENCES sellers(id)
);

INSERT INTO sellers(id, name, rating) values(1, 'Roger', 3);
INSERT INTO sellers(id, name, rating) values(2, 'Penny', 5);

INSERT INTO items(id, name, sellerId) values(1, 'Notebook', 2);
INSERT INTO items(id, name, sellerId) values(2, 'Stapler', 1);
INSERT INTO items(id, name, sellerId) values(3, 'Pencil', 2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the wrong join, here's a corrected query;

```
SELECT items.name, sellers.name
FROM items
inner JOIN sellers
    on items.sellerId=sellers.id
WHERE rating > 4
ORDER BY sellerId
```

You're joining on id = id, you want sellerid = id

Notice in your table definition that item.sellerId is the field that joins to seller.id

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  sellerId INTEGER REFERENCES sellers(id)
);
```

Comment: You want the join that is in both tables? sellerId is only in 1?

Comment: No, you're joining sellers.id (the unique identifier for your seller) to items.id (the unique identifier on your items table). The link between these two tables is the seller.id to items.sellerid. Notice that items.sellerid is a foreign key to seller.id in your table definition.

Comment: I didn't saw the foreign key when i was reading it. Thank you, you made it crystal clear!

Answer (score 1):

You need to join on the correct column:

```
SELECT i.name, s.name
FROM items i INNER JOIN
     sellers s
     ON i.sellerid = s.id
----------^
WHERE rating > 4
ORDER BY i.sellerId
```

Note that I also introduced table aliases and qualified column names.  These make a query easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT items.name, sellers.name 
FROM items, sellers 
WHERE items.sellerId = sellers.id and sellers.rating>4;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the right query:

```sql
        SELECT items.name as items, sellers.name as sellers
        FROM sellers
        INNER JOIN items
        ON (sellers.id = items.sellerid)
        WHERE sellers.rating > 4
```

Comment: This is virtually identical to Gordon's answer from 2016. Can you point out the differences and explain why you think yours is better or more correct?